# How can i get the Size(bytes) of a Solana Transaction?

Tags: solana-program

I want to get the size of a transaction in bytes so that i can check if its less than 1232 bytes and does not exceeds the transaction limit

Comment: What kind of client? Rust?

Answer (score 3):

I would need a bit more information I think, but transaction.Serialize() gives you the byte array and then you can check the size.